# Extracting images and Alt tags

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to use Xpath through Google Sheets ImportXML to extract the Alt tag from a specific image on a page.

I have tried:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//img[contains(@src,A2)]/@src")
```

A1 contains the page URL
A2 contains the path to the image

It provides the Alt tags for all images on that page, not just the one I tried to constrain the result to, using `[contains(@src,A2)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have "A2" within a string, which Sheets isn't interpreting as a cell reference.  You also need quotes round string literals in XPath expressions, and your XPath as written ought to return the src attribute (not alt), so:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//img[contains(@src,'" & A2 & "')]/@alt")
```

should help.  I'm unable to test this though.