# How do I import images from an HTML table into Google Sheets using IMPORTXML?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to import portions of [this](https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Villager/New_Leaf) data table into a spreadsheet in order to reference it for other sheets. I've been able to get the text of the table using the `=IMPORTHTML` formula, but to my understanding the only way to import the images besides manually using `=IMAGE()` for each entry (which I'd like to avoid if possible since the table has around 400 entries) is to use `=IMPORTXML`, which I've been having difficulties with since I'm unfamiliar with the XML format.

Here's the formula I'm using for the text portions of the table, since I only need data from a few columns: `=QUERY(ImportHtml("https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Villager/New_Leaf", "table", 1), "SELECT Col2,Col3,Col5")`

I was able to find a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309304/google-sheets-import-multiple-html-table-images) that had this solution by majinnaibu:

```
ArrayFormula(
  Image(
    ImportXML(
      "https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Hisui_Pok%C3%A9dex_number",
      "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr//td/following-sibling::th/a/img/@src"
    ),
    4,
    64,
    64
  )
)
```

I tested this in my sheet and it worked with the Pokémon images, but I've been struggling to find the XPath query I need for the images I'm trying to use. That's the part I need help with.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your expected value? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Related question: [Extracting images and Alt tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32986030/1330560)

Comment: Related resource (Google Docs Editors Help): [Scraping Images and Alt Text from a website](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/130834893/scraping-images-and-alt-text-from-a-website?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=QUERY({QUERY({IMPORTXML("https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Villager/New_Leaf","//img[contains(@src,'Texture')]/@alt"),IMPORTXML("https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Villager/New_Leaf","//img[contains(@src,'Texture')]/@src")},"select Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Image name', Col2 'URL'"),QUERY({ImportHtml("https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Villager/New_Leaf", "table", 1)}, "SELECT Col2,Col3,Col5")},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5")`

---

The answer consists of two nested `QUERY/IMPORTXML` & `QUERY/IMPORTHTML`.

- `QUERY/IMPORTXML`

  - XPath = Image name: `"//img[contains(@src,'Texture')]/@alt")`
  - XPath = Image URL: `"//img[contains(@src,'Texture')]/@src"`
- `QUERY/IMPORTHTML` - this is the OP's own formula to extract the text

---

**RESULTS - Extract**

[image: sample]